# How to know what timezone to set for an NSDateFormatter when converting from an NSDate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a function which converts an NSString in RFC3339 to NSDate using an NSDateFormatter, but I don't know how to take account of the timezone doing the reverse.

The relevant part of the string to NSDate conversion is:

```
    // The result of a call to systemTimeZone is cached by the app automatically, if the user changes it that change isn't 
    // reflected unless resetSystemTimeZone is called to clear the cache.
    [NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone]; 
    NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale;
    enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [sRFC3339DateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
    if ([fromString hasSuffix:@"Z"] || [fromString hasSuffix:@"z"])
    {
        [sRFC3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    }
    else 
    {
        [sRFC3339DateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    }

[sRFC3339DateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"];
```

My question is, when converting in the other direction from an NSDate to an NSString, how do I know what to call setTimeZone with? When going from string to NSDate its by looking at the absense/presense of Z. But if I have an NSDate how do I know what time zone to set the formatter to?

Comment: It can get a little confusing sometimes, because if you NSDump an NSDate it does display a timezone.  Apparently the original timezone is squirreled away inside the object somewhere, but it's only accessible via `description`, and it does not participate in any date conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your NSDate is stored as UTC/GMT timezone. So when you are converting that to a string, you pick the time zone you want the string displayed in. There is no "right" answer. It's whatever you want to display.

Comment: Your first sentence is incorrect. `NSDate`s do not _have_ timezones -- they simply represent a moment in time. Everything else is spot on, though.

Comment: Hmm, I think my first sentence is fine. It's a moment in time with no time zone offset, which is the same as UTC (no offset). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Unix

Comment: No, there is no offset, because there is no zone. If I have an `NSDate` that represents the moment the ball drops in Times Square in 2012, that _same_ `NSDate` also represents 5 in the morning in London. Looking at a date with a time zone is an interpretation.

Comment: Yes, the moment you drop the ball in times square is 5 in the morning in London and 4am in UTC. And lo and behold, if you display your NSDate for that moment with no time zone applied it will say 4am. You cannot offset a moment in time without a reference point (what would you add the offset to?). I guarantee you that you can never get an NSDate to print out differently than a UTC time zone unless you supply an offset. No time zone is the same thing as saying UTC.

Comment: From Apple's docs: "The sole primitive method of NSDate, timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate, provides the basis for all the other methods in the NSDate interface. This method returns a time value relative to an absolute reference date—the first instant of 1 January 2001, GMT." <--Note that GMT is the time zone used for reference point for storing NSDate.

Comment: Actually in thinking about this more, it is wrong to say NSDate don't have a time zone, or that UTC is the same as no time zone. They are seconds since Jan 1, 2001 GMT, so they do have a time zone by definition. It's GMT/UTC. It just happens, the offset for that particular time zone is 0.

Comment: I'm not saying that UTC is the same as no time zone, I'm saying that time zones _don't even enter the picture_. Time zones only have an effect when you inspect or display the information, and an `NSDate` _does not_ have a time zone associated with it. That absolute reference date _looks like_ the first instant of 1 January 2001 if you're at the Royal Observatory, but if you look at a clock anywhere else in the world, the same moment of time has a different representation.

Comment: Of course GMT is *associated* to NSDate. It's the reference time zone by which you can obtain all the other representations anywhere else in the world. Without that association, you couldn't do the conversion. All NSDate objects are stored as seconds from Jan 1, 2001 *in GMT time zone*. The assertion that there is no time zone associated to NSDate is plain wrong. See the wikipedia article and the apple docs.

Comment: Think of it this way: if NSDate was defined as seconds from Jan 1, 2001 somewhere/anywhere in the universe it would be useless. Without that association to the GMT time zone in its definition/storage, it wouldn't work. Time zone absolutely enters the picture.

Comment: The reference date is a time, _t_, which, in the Greenwich Mean Time Zone, is ***represented*** as Jan 1, 2001. Other places, it's represented differently. On Mars, it's represented differently, but it's still the same point in time. We're talking past each other at this point, but here's a doc link for you anyways: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtTimeZones.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000185-SW4 «NSDate objects store dates in absolute time. For example, the date object [...] represents 4:00 PM CDT, 5:00 EDT, and so on.»

Comment: Ugh. The only reason you can *represent* it differently in other places is because it is *associated* to GMT as the reference time zone when it is stored. If the number stored (seconds from reference date) wasn't associated to any time zone to begin with you'd be unable to represent it accurately anywhere in the universe (including Mars or at the Royal Observatory). The only reason it works is because it is stored as a time interval (seconds) from a date (Jan 1, 2001) *in a known time zone* (GMT). Without all 3 of these variables together it wouldn't work. Do you disagree with this assertion?

Comment: Here is a simple way to understand it. Assume the moment in time, t, could be represented in n different ways (you may argue that n is finite on earth and infinite in the universe). When you save an NSDate it doesn't save all n representations. It stores 1 representation. Which is that moment in time represented in GMT time zone. You can then read that particular representation and translate it to all other n-1 representations.